# Edit headlines (header level) FLUID Powered TYPO3 fluidcontent_core instead of CSS_Styled_Content

Tags: header, typo3, fluid, fedext

How can I edit my Header info fluidcontent_core Extension. I use it instead of the 'normal' CSS_Styled_Content with `FLUIDPAGES 3.1.2`, `FLUX 7.1.2`, `FLUIDCONTENT 4.1.2`, `FLUIDCONTENT_CORE 4.1.1` and `VHS 2.1.4` - the latest versions of [FLuidTYPO3](https://fluidtypo3.org/).

For example, I need an additional `<div class="text-center">|</div>` for my `<h1>` Header, like this

```
<div class="text-center">
  <h1>{textBla}</h1>
</div>
```

**How can I add additional HTML-Code for h1 - h6** or change the labels 1,2,3,4,5,6 to Text Strings!?

[image: Try to use own labels and wrap <h?>|</h?>]

In further projects I use lib.stdheader / tt_content for this case. But now it's all about FLUID. I've read the Dok, but I'm still helpless ..  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can use a new FLUX Content Element, only for my `<h1>` headline, maybe in a new group and ignore all standard content elements from TYPO3?! But that will be only a workaround. It's better to edit the standard elements from `fluidcontent_core`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the templates of content_core are all in the Private dir of the ext. itself.
If you take a look at them, you will see that the headers are rendered from a comma separated string set in the setup.ts and deflated as an array.
You can make your ow array or create your own dropdown with whatever data you like. It is flux based so almost limitless.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, rob-ot! I think I've got it.

`setup.ts`

```
plugin.tx_fluidcontentcore {
  settings {
    header {
      classNames = testheader, blatest       
    }
    container {
      classNames = hello
    }
  }
}
```

I leave the `header level` at constants `types = 1,2,3,4,5,6` and add new `classNames`. For my case I add also a new container className, so my output is like:

```
<div class="hello">
  <h1 class="blatest">
    Header only level 1
  </h1>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks!